# AS2 setMask doesn't work for me on Flash 8

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

What am I doing wrong here?  It works if "square" is vector rendered but not if its a loaded image from an url.  Code follows

```
stop();
this.Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
this.Security.allowDomain("*") 

this.createEmptyMovieClip("square", 1);
this.createEmptyMovieClip("triangle", 2);
triangle.beginFill(0xFFFFFF,100);
triangle.moveTo(10,10);
triangle.lineTo(10,50);
triangle.lineTo(50,10);
triangle.endFill();


var MCL:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();
var mListener:Object = new Object();
mListener.onLoadInit = function(target_mc:MovieClip) {

    target_mc.setMask(triangle);
};
MCL.addListener(mListener);
MCL.loadClip("http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5167/5257133700_64698a6cea_s.jpg",square);

return;
```

Comment: I've also tried square.cacheAsBitmap=true; and triangle.cacheAsBitmap=true; after CreateEmptyMovieClip and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Wow I figured it out minutes after posting (after 4 hours of racking my brain).

I changed to onLoadComplete (instead of Init) and all is now well.